# How to request data from firestore by bringing in the value request.auth

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm learning to create a simple application using Angular by utilizing firestore realtime database.

Here is the query that I use to retrieve data

```
let query = this.firestore.collection('notes', ref => ref
    .where('noteUser', '==', this.data['id'])
    .where('noteStatus', '==', 0)
    .orderBy('noteUpdateAt', 'desc')
);
let dataNew0 = query.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
dataNew0.subscribe(ss => {
    this.myDataNote = ss;
});
```

Everything went smoothly when I used the default firestore rules settings.

When I want to use it in production mode, I change the rules to be like this as in the documentation:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /{document=**} {
         allow read, write: if request.auth != null
      }
   }
}
```

The question is: How do I apply the user id when get data into the `request.auth`  variable so that it is read by firestore rules settings.

Comment: How do you signin (authenticate) the user?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec - Registered users can log in using their username. This is handled by the backend I created with express.js

Comment: So you don’t use the Firebase Authentication service?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec - Yes, I don't use it. Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) on Security Rules, the `request.auth` variable contains the authentication information for the client requesting data **if your app uses Firebase Authentication.**

Comment: Then do you know the best firebase rules if you don't use Firebase Authentication?

Comment: "the best firebase rules" => It is impossible to answer without much more details on your authentication mechanism. Since you use angularfire I don't think (i'm not a specialist of angularfire) you can modify the requests sent to the Firestore backend. The solution is most probably to implement this authorisation layer in the backend you created with express.js.